# Haskell stack with global ghc

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

Is it possible to use `stack` with an already installed `ghc` without `stack` installing a local copy of `ghc` or `cabal`?

Comment: This is covered in the [stack FAQ](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq.html#i-already-have-ghc-installed-can-i-still-use-stack).

Comment: For increased visibility: The option you need is `--system-ghc`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If the `ghc` in `PATH` is of right version for the selected snapshot, `stack` will happily use it.

```
% ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.4

% stack --resolver=lts-2.22 install packdeps
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-2.22 specified on command line
packdeps-0.4.1: unregistering
packdeps-0.4.2: download
...

% stack --resolver=nightly-2015-12-25 install packdeps
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: nightly-2015-12-25 specified on command line
Compiler version mismatched, found ghc-7.8.4 (x86_64), but expected minor version match with ghc-7.10.3 (x86_64) (based on resolver setting in /Users/phadej/.stack/global/stack.yaml).
Try running "stack setup" to install the correct GHC into /Users/phadej/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/
```

You can also skip ghc check `--skip-ghc-check`:

```
% stack --resolver=nightly-2015-12-25 --skip-ghc-check install packdeps
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: nightly-2015-12-25 specified on command line
split-0.2.2: configure
...
```

but that might be a **bad** idea

Comment: I believe that by default `stack` WILL NOT use the global GHC installation, even if its version matches the project's `resolver` setting. But it is possible - [Shaun the Sheep's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469955/haskell-stack-with-global-ghc#comment56695023_34469955) points to the documentation that explains the available options.