# global GHC from Stack?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I have happily installed Stack, and run my code with `stack ghci` or `stack exec` and whatnot.
I would like to use [vscode-haskell](https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell), and that requires a `ghc` available in the PATH.

Is it possible to create a `ghc` command available globally using stack? (e.g. some suitable commans in my powershell/bash profile)

ps. Close duplicates that did not help me are

1. [Using stack ghc as replacement of ghc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191044/using-stack-ghc-as-replacement-of-ghc)  but only talks about makefiles
2. [Haskell Stack doesn't use system Ghc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460120/haskell-stack-doesnt-use-system-ghc) is about making Stack use a system GHC *if it is available* which is not the case for me
3. [Haskell stack with global ghc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469955/haskell-stack-with-global-ghc) which is close to a dupplicate of [2]

Comment: I think vscode-haskell doesn't require ghc if you are working on a stack package, see https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell#requirements. So maybe you could just make the code you're working on a stack package?

Comment: I guess you can configure vscode extension so it looks directly into the folder `stack` has installed ghc, normally somthing like `~/.stack/bin` but it depends on your system.

Comment: @Noughtmare yeah that is an option. But I mostly work on small hacker-rank style challenges, so making a project for each seems like a hassle

Comment: @lsmor I can't find any such executable. One often calls `stack ghc` and the GHC call is run through the `stack` executable. Am I searching in the wrong folder? PS. I'm on windows.

Comment: Another thing that might work is running `stack exec vscode`, then it might get the proper ghc path, but that is just a guess.

Comment: try running `stack path`. It will show all paths used by `stack`, including `compiler-exe`. Anyway, even if you are using just for small hacker-rank stuff it would be better to create a project. You can use a different file for each exercise. That would help if you want to use common libraries like `containers` for example

Comment: ah. ok. very nice. found it in `"$env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.4\bin"`. I could accept that as an answer if you like writing it as such.

Comment: ...but most likely I'll take your advice on organizing in a stack project.